# Have default Group for new Gitlab User

Tags: permissions, gitlab

The title shoud be pretty straigh forward but here the detailed explanation. I have a self hosted Gitlab instance and I would like that new people that sign in fall directly into a _user_group so they can directly access some project.

The behavior I have today is the following one.

- User sign-up
- Request access/Admin grant access to this group.

This is a bit anoying as admins have to be aware that new user signed-up. I was not able to find what I wanted in the gitlab documentation nor in the different permission your can set for a group (Internal/private/public). I a nutshell, I would need the "public" visibility of a group with the "private" permission for clone etc...

I was thinking maybe of a script trigerred when a new user sign-up, but this can be hard to integrate and I do not really want to modify gitlab code.

If you have any idea I'll take any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, this feature seems to require LDAP authentication and a premium license. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#manage-group-memberships-via-ldap.